# Bluetooth speaker connects to input rather than output - seems related to macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, system-settings, speakers

I’ve got a bluetooth speaker (Bose Mini II SoundLink) that I’m trying to connect to my Mac. I was playing music through Tidal and it was working normally but then it suddenly disconnected, and now whenever I try and reconnect it, it will show up in input devices as it has a mic (under System Preferences > Sound) but not under output devices.

It seems after updating to macOS Big Sur my bluetooth devices are consistently having problems because some headphones of mine also refuse to connect with the audio unless I redo pairing every time.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?